# How to use Siri Extension on an existing project with Deployment Target 8.0

Tags: ios, siri

I have a project on Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8. The deployment target for this project is from 8.0. 
Is possible that Siri Extension can be used in this app? 
It means, only if users installed the app on ios10-iphone, then siri extension works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The minimum deployment target for Siri is **iOS 10**. Apple has exposed SirKit in iOS 10 so we can't set the minimum deployment target to something less than iOS 10.

Having said that, you can keep your original app target as it is i.e. `8.0` but when you create Siri extension ( also Siri UI extension), you need to set deployment target to minimum of 10.0. This way all the targets build successfully. Please note that you need minimum of `xcode8`.